# How do I request/manipulate "currently selected days" in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Context: http://fullcalendar.io

With "selectable" set to true (and a custom 'addEventSource'), it's possible to drag-select ranges of days (not calendar events).  The ranges themselves can be noncontiguous.

With that in mind and without having to also add "Events", how do I:

1) . . .programmatically request a collection/array of "currently selected days" from the FullCalendar object *after* all days have been selected?

2) . . ."deselect" individual calendar items (rather than en masse)?

Answer (score 0):

On the [link you provided](https://fullcalendar.io/), hit [F-12], then [ctrl]+[shift]+[c] (Keyboard shortcut for Chrome) to select a specific element to inspect.

You'll soon see that the calendar is a complex set of tables within a main table and that every event is a `td` possibly "colspaned" over multiple calendar days.

So I would say **no** to question #1. Can't select a date.
If possible, it is complicated enought to try another tool first.

Obviously, question #2 is also **no**.

FullCalendar is usefull to show events, select or drag them...
But not to select/deselect one or multiple dates.

You'll have to use another tool to achive this.